# Error al mostrar animacion libGDX

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

Al dibujar la animacion solo coje la primera textura, no recorre la array y no se por que...

Aqui dejo el fragmento del render, cuando llamo a la animación

```js
 if(juegoAcabado){
            // Si hi ha hagut col·lisió: Reproduïm l'explosió
            //stackOverflow EXPLOSION bucle
            sb.draw(explosionAnim.getKeyFrame(0, false), (nave.getPosition().x + nave.NAVE_ANCHO / 2) - 32, nave.getPosition().y + nave.NAVE_ALTO / 2 - 32, 64, 64);
```

Comment: Es un poco difícil entender el código sin el contexto, no sabemos de qué clase es cada variable. Te agradecería que editaras la pregunta y lo indicaras. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente el problema esté en **getKeyFrame(0, false)**.

[Fíjate en la API de Animation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html#getKeyFrame-float-) El primer parámetro ha de ser un valor float con el tiempo transcurrido desde el inicio de la animación.

Si siempre es cero entonces siempre mostrará el primer frame.

Necesitarás pasarle una variable float que cuente el tiempo de animación transcurrido. En el segundo parámetro probablemente quieras usar true para una animación en bucle.